# Understanding the the transitive dependencies of the Kotlin Standard Library with Maven

Tags: kotlin, maven

I'm trying to understand the relationship between different versions of Kotlin libraries the Maven Kotlin plugin.  As the configuration below shows, I'm setting my Kotlin version to `1.8.20-RC2`, but for reasons I don't understand, it's getting version `1.3.72` of the Kotlin stdlib.  There are features in stdlib version `1.5` that I want and I can't understand why I'm only getting version `1.3`.

I've got this in my `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <kotlin.version>1.8.20-RC2</kotlin.version>
</properties>
```

and under `<depenencies>`,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and under `<build><plugins>...</plugins></build>` section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>

    // lots more stuff here
</plugin>
```

But then, I ran `mvn dependency:tree`, and look what it shows:

```
// lots of other dependencies listed
[INFO] +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:jar:1.8.20-RC2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.3.72:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:jar:1.3.72:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:13.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:jar:1.3.72:compile
[INFO] \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:jar:1.8.20-RC2:test
```

I'm not an expert at this, but if I understand this right, version `1.8.20-RC2` is bringing in `1.3.72` as a transitive dependency.  I confirmed that I am unable to use a function in my code, `firstNotNullOfOrNull` that is not available in `1.3` but is available on versions `1.5` or later.

Can someone explain what is going on here, and how I can get a later version of the stdlib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your specific issue here, because the artifact does depend on the correct stdlib and stdlib-jdk7, as we can see in the pom on Maven Central:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.8.20-RC2/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.8.20-RC2.pom

But anyway, note that those `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7` and `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` artifacts have been merged with the regular `kotlin-stdlib` [since Kotlin 1.8](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew18.html#updated-jvm-compilation-target), so you shouldn't use them anymore.

Instead, just use `kotlin-stdlib` directly, it might solve the problem altogether.

Comment: This did the trick.  Thank you!  Though I wish it was more intuitive, like we would get some kind of error when doing it wrong instead of getting some weird behavior like this.

Answer (score 0):

My pom has this

```
        <kotlin.version>1.8.10</kotlin.version>
...    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and I get what you might be expecting on the dependency graph

```
INFO] +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.8.10:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:jar:1.8.10:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:13.0:provided
```

My guess about what is happening is that some other dependency is forcing the version down.

What IDE are you using.  If you are using IntelliJ is has a Maven analyser which will help you find that a transitive dependency is being overriden.

Obviously you should find the source of that, but if you cannot you can just re-declare the `kotlin-stdlib-common` explicitly at the top level like this:

```
        <kotlin.version>1.8.10</kotlin.version>
...    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-common</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```